# Oracle Apex Trigger to Capture timestamp in PST

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I have a trigger in place to capture the `TIMESTAMP` when the User enters a line or data into a table, however this trigger is not capturing the right time (should be displayed in PST) and shows time with offset of +7 hours.
I am new to Apex development, could someone assist me to convert the time to PST or assist me to modify this trigger.

```
create or replace trigger "CC_RESULTS_T1"
AFTER
insert on "CC_RESULTS"
for each row
BEGIN
  DECLARE 
    vTS timestamp;
  BEGIN 
    vTS := systimestamp;
    INSERT INTO CC_TIMESTAMPS(CC_ID,TIME_STAMP) 
    VALUES(:new.ID,SYSTIMESTAMP);
  END;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to take a look at
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch4datetime.htm#NLSPG253

the new_time function takes two parameters, timezone1, timezone2
this function returns the date and time in time zone timezone2 when date and time in time zone timezone1 are date.

for example:

```
SELECT to_date('19-MAR-2014 02:00:00','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS') "GMT", 
       NEW_TIME(to_date('19-MAR-2014 02:00:00','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS'), 'GMT', 'PST') AS"PST" from dual;
```

you can get time zone offset like GMT, PST, AST from oracle documentation for new_time function:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions105.htm#SQLRF00671

also you can take a look for time zone view in database dictionary as:

```
SELECT tzname, tzabbrev ,tz_offset(t.tzname) FROM v$timezone_names  t;
```

Comment: Thank you for the response the current DB time zone is -5:00 I want this time in PST. I am not sure how to change this SQL trigger statement